# Issue in getting notification during calling in android

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, dialing

I am a new developer of android app. I am doing an app which is dialing a number after getting that number through push notification. This was successfully done, however when I am sending another push notification to cancel the dialing call, that notification is not reached at android . After call end that notification is reached. Please help me out.

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ I am using code form the above tutorial link for sending push notification. On my GCMIntentService's onMessage() I am calling a number using Intent.Action_Call. However when i send  the second notification to end the call with a special flag to be checked in onMessage(). Notification never arrives while the outgoing call is on.

Comment: I think that your problem is that when you are calling, the mobile network will be disconnected because your phone cannot handle cellular connection next to the data connection, try it while you are connected to a WiFi network. Wifi will stay connected when you are calling.

Comment: I am using WiFi connectivity @Ion Aalbers

Comment: I had this same issue while using the mobile data as the data receive/sent stops during call or other cellular activities. I had to use the cellular data services as deliver of notification so I had to sacrifice that. Google should be aware of this delay in deliver of notification so that every features should be used using any connection.

Comment: You should post some code in reference to the issue as this may go off-topic.